# Pagerduty how to get individual schedule with api v2

Tags: rest

in PagerDuty api v1 one can get the schedule for a individual user the it is shown on that page :[here](https://v1.developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/schedules/entries)

How can I produce the same result with v2 API?

I tried using the same endpoint as in v1 but it returned

```
{'error': {'code': 2100, 'message': 'Not Found'}}
```

For me the documentation of PagerDuty for v2 is quite difficult to get useful info from.

Answer (score 1):

"I tried using the same endpoint as in v1 ..."

I assume your endpoints looked like this:

V1 `https://my-account.pagerduty.com/api/v1/schedules/P538IZH/entries?since=2017-03-01&until=2017-03-20"` (returns list of entries for the date range)

V2 `https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/P538IZH/entries?since=2017-03-01&until=2017-03-20"` (returns error `2100`)

In API V2 you would exclude the `/entries` portion of the endpoint:

`https://api.pagerduty.com/schedules/P538IZH/?since=2017-03-01&until=2017-03-20"`

[This API call can be made right from the docs.](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/v2/page/api-reference#!/Schedules/get_schedules_id)

If you are looking for an ID to use in the `api.pagerduty.com/schedules/<ID>` [try the list schedules call first](https://v2.developer.pagerduty.com/v2/page/api-reference#!/Schedules/get_schedules)